# Assigning one NSString constant to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, constants

I want to define `NSString` constants and have one of them refer to another. For example:

```
NSString * const kUrlGoogle = @"http://google.com";
NSString * const kUrlApple = @"http://apple.com";
NSString * const kUrlMicrosoft = @"http://microsoft.com";

NSString * const kUrlDefault = kUrlGoogle;
```

When I try doing this, I get a compile time error on the `kUrlDefault` line:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Is there any way to assign `kUrlDefault` to one of the strings above without resorting to macro usage?

Here are a few reasons why this can be useful:

- I could test for equality without having to call the `isEqual` method.
- If I update the constant, `kUrlDefault` will automatically get the new value (as with all constants).
- Keeping all the constants together in one file at the same location.

Comment: "I could test for equality without having to call the isEqual method." Don't count on that always working for the matches case. Further that is a premature optimization.

Comment: @Zaph: It was just provided as an example, I'm not planning on actually doing it. Do you have a link to a website that describes why it may not always work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to step back and think about if the string needs to be defined as a const.

Clearly the string isn't a constant since you are trying to assign a new value to it - and that is not possible since you specifically instructed the compiler to make sure the value wasn't changed by using the const keyword.

If the string resides as a property in a class you could make it a read-only property - i.e. accessor method but no setter method. You would then be able to construct your string as you wish in the class internally while keeping the callers from changing the value.

Comment: I'm setting the value exactly one time, and this is precisely at the same time the variable is defined. Furthermore, the value I am assigning to it is what I would hope to be a constant (hence my usage of `const` in the other strings). This should be a valid usage of constants since if I do the same exact thing with `NSInteger`s, for example, the compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1) Set `kUrlDefault` in the `+ (void)initialize` method of the class. This has one major downside though. It would require that the class be referenced in some manner prior to any use of the constant. Otherwise the constant won't yet be initialized.

2) Refactor the `kUrlDefault` constant into a class method. The implementation of the method would return the desired default value. One advantage of this approach is that it add scope to the global because it would sort of become a class level variable instead of an app level constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Constants set outside any function cannot be dynamic.**

You can use this method in a function, not outside, maybe it can works with C++ or objective-C++ (C++ standards are more flexible with that)

I would use this solution (i don't know if this method will fit your needs):

```
NSString *kUrlGoogle = @"http://google.com";
NSString *kUrlApple = @"http://apple.com";
NSString *kUrlMicrosoft = @"http://microsoft.com";
```

and later, in other place, you can get var you want with:

```
extern NSString *kUrlGoogle;
```